# array values in for loop stops page from loading and creates an unlimited loop php

Tags: php

I've got a page where I run a while loop from a database.  I ended up needing some of the information before I displayed the page, so I ended up having to set up an array to store the while loop information.  Once the while loop completes, then the page loads.

```
        $first = $data[$key]['order'][$data_order_id]['lowest_staff_markup'];
        $second = $data[$key]['order'][$data_order_id]['lowest_markup'];
```

If I use `echo $first .' ... '. $second;` it returns `12 ... 30`

**the values are being set correctly.  The array works**

Now I need to set up a for loop to loop between the numbers.  If I manually put in 12 and 30 it works great.  But the moment I try to place $first and $second in, the entire for loop freezes the page and creates an unlimited loop of `12`

```
echo '<select name="markup['. $cart_result['product_table'] .':'. $cart_result['product_id'] .']" />';  // fix this
        for ($mu = $first;
        $mu <= $second;
        $mu++) {
            echo '<option value="'. $data[$key]['order'][$data_order_id]['markup_key'] .'">'. $mu .' %</option>';
            }
        echo '</select>';
```

Any idea why this is happening?  I've been staring at this code for entirely too long trying to understand it.  I've tried everything I can think of even though I'm sure the answer is obvious.

**Like I said, the for loop works perfectly if I place the numbers in manually so I know the code itself works.**

Sorry if there is any typos.  I took unneeded portions fo the code out like "selected = selected" conditions, etc.  I only placed the amount of code needed for the problem.

Comment: `var_dump($first); var_dump($second);` ?

Comment: `string(3) "12 " string(2) "30"`

Comment: theres a space in the first string..hmm..would that be causing issues?

Comment: try casting them to integers maybe ?

Comment: Yes.  Using `$mu = (int) $first` would solve the problem.

Comment: now I'm trying to figure out how in the world there is a space after one.  This is all pulling from database...great...back to the original code...haha.  Thanks for the help!  AymDev, place as an answer please :)

Comment: I'm officially an idiot.  I was adding a space to it for testing to make sur ethe variables were returning correctly earlier in the code....i hate myself now....haha just kidding. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @KDJ Done, with explanation (else it would be useless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging in the comments with OP using

```
var_dump($first);
var_dump($second);
```

Appeared that `$first` contains a space:

> string(3) "12 "
>   string(2) "30"

**Solution:**
Casting the strings to integers solve this issue:

```
for ($mu = (int)$first; $mu <= (int)$second; $mu++) {
    // code here ...
}
```

Comment: you rock!  I don't know why I always ignore using "var_dump();" . I think that may be a complex of mine like a guy asking for directions :P  Thanks for the assistance.  Everything is working like a charm now

Comment: You're welcome, @KDJ ! Don't forget to use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) while debugging arrays too, using it like `echo '<pre>' . print_r($arr, true) . '</pre>';`. Accept my answer as it solved your issue ;-)

Comment: sorry stepped away.  Was waiting for SO to allow me to accept.